# Window.location with intent href on Chrome for android closes page

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome

I am trying to have users be redirected to an app when they click an email link. I am doing this by adding a `open-app=true` parameter in the url and detecting it using javascript and then doing a window.location.href assignment. However the issue that I'm running into is that Chrome for Android is closing the browser tab after redirecting to the App store or App if they have it installed. However, it doesn't close the browser tab if the user clicks a button to go to the App store. Here is a general run down of the code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var function open_android_app_or_play_store(app_path) {
        return ("intent:/"+app_path+"/#Intent;scheme="+settings_obj.app_scheme+";package="+settings_obj.android_app_package+";end");
    }
    var url_params=getUrlParams(window.location.href);
    var app_path=window.location.pathname;
    if(url_params['open_app']) {
        window.location = open_android_app_or_play_store(app_path);
    }
}
```

The button click uses open_android_app_or_play_store(app_path) as well.